# How to replace HTML comments with empty string in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, replace

I am trying to remove comments from HTML in Javascript but not working correctly. I need only plain HTML except comments

```js
let sourceHTML = document.querySelector(".mySelector").innerHTML;
sourceHTML = sourceHTML.replace(/<--!(?:.|\n)*?-->/gm, '');
console.log(sourceHTML);
```

```html
<div class="mySelector">
    <!--Main content -->
    <p>HTML content...</p>
</div>
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Let the dom do the parsing. It is a better parser than regex for html. https://jsfiddle.net/obz19hwy/ A comment is a node and has nodeType = 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have `!` character at wrong place in your regex

```
/<--!(?:.|\n)*?-->/
    |________________  This should be before `--` i.e:-  !--
```

```js
let sourceHTML = document.querySelector(".mySelector").innerHTML;
sourceHTML = sourceHTML.replace(/<!--(?:.|\n)*?-->/gm, '');
console.log(sourceHTML);
```

```html
<div class="mySelector">
    <!--Main content -->
    <p>HTML content...</p>
</div>
```